# Python requests - using twitter search

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use requests to get data from twitter but when i run my code i get this error: **simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

This is my code so far:

```
import requests

url = 'https://twitter.com/search?q=memes&src=typed_query'
results = requests.get(url)
better_results = results.json()
better_results['results'][1]['text'].encode('utf-8')
print(better_results)
```

Comment: Twitter has a free API that you can use. There is even a supporting python package called Tweepy. I'd recommend this as Twitter explicitly says not to scrape data apart from their API.

Answer (score 1):

because you are making a request to a `dynamic` website.

when we are making a request to a dynamic website we must render the html first in order to receive all the content that we were expecting to receive.

just making the request is not enough.

other libraries such as `requests_html` render the html and javascript in background using a `lite browser`.

you can try this code:

```
# pip install requests_html
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://twitter.com/search?q=memes&src=typed_query'

session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get(url)

# rendering part
response.html.render(timeout=20)

better_results = response.json()
better_results['results'][1]['text'].encode('utf-8')
print(better_results)
```

Comment: it gives me this error: File "c:/Users/gassp/OneDrive/Namizje/Python.projects/twitter_search.py", line 9, in <module>
    response.html.render(timeout=20) and than it gives me another error: OSError: [WinError 14001] The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.

Comment: And do you know what do i need to do to get images too?

Comment: Is there any other way to scrape twitter and get its text and images?

Comment: sorry, i dont know any other way to scrape dynamic websites. in the past i used `requests_html`, but at the moment i receive some error and i dont understand why.

Comment: do you know how to fix it?